# Vim omni completion: continue typing to select desired item

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

Consider the scenerio when I have typed:

```
file.f
```

When I type <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> the omni-completion popup is shown and the first item is selected. This is what I see:

```
file.fileno
       ---------
       fileno()  <-- highlighted
       flush()
       ---------
```

Notice that the text that I have typed ("file.f") has already changed to:

```
file.fileno
```

I can move selection down in the list to 'flush', press ENTER and it will end up with

```
f.flush()
```

But I would like to continue typing the desired method name instead of using arrow keys. I.e. I would like to type "file.f", "Ctrl-X Ctrl-O", "l" and get either

```
file.fileno
       ---------
       flush()
       ---------
```

or

```
file.fileno
       ---------
       fileno()
       flush()  <-- highlighted
       ---------
```

Is this possible? Maybe some omni-completion settings have to be changed, or I should use a different keys combination instead of <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add:
`set completeopt+=longest`
to your .vimrc file.

This will tell omnicomplete to only insert the longest common text of all the matches.

For more information, run the command `:help completeopt` while in vim.

Comment: An other way is to click CTRL+P, and type some more text.